# More convenient way to convert to seconds since midnight in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have this very bulky way of converting from TRADETIME in the format of

```
'20150513T082207'
```

But I would like to know if there is a shorter way of doing this conversion to make the code more efficient and clean. Though this yields the correct result.

```
select date_format(str_to_date(TRADETIME, '%Y%m%dT%H%i%s'), '%H') * 60*60 + 
date_format(str_to_date(TRADETIME, '%Y%m%dT%H%i%s'), '%i') * 60 +
date_format(str_to_date(TRADETIME, '%Y%m%dT%H%i%s'), '%s') as TRADETIME from NFDATA limit 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could give it a go to [TIME_TO_SEC](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-to-sec):

```
SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(str_to_date(TRADETIME, '%Y%m%dT%H%i%s')) as tradetime 
FROM NFDATA limit 1
```